# how to reload/refresh previous url in angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, angular, web-applications, router

In my scenario of current Angular 7 application, I'm navigation user to connection lost component if the network stopped. And I'm doing this with `skipLocationChange:true` flag, like below

```
this.router.navigate(['/connection-lost'], {skipLocationChange: true});
```

Now if the network start working. I want to reload the previous page by clicking on the reload button from `ConnectionLostComponent`.

I tried it by `router.navigate([router.url])`, but `router.url` giving the URL `/connection-lost` not which is showing in **address bar**

For example, if the user is on the address page('/addresses'), and connection lost. then the user is navigated to `ConnectionLostComponent` on the same URL('/addresses'). Now if the user click on the reload button, then it should load address page

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that I found is to use `navigateByUrl` method of the `Router`.

like :

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(this.location.path(true));
```

here `location` from ('@angular/common') gives the exact path which is showing in the **address bar**.